# Ext JS Table Layout how to force only last element on the right

Tags: extjs

I have a page with 3 elements created on the page and a 4th element (D) being loaded from a different script file using #parse. What I want to do is to force table layout to align them like this

```
 ____ ___
| A  |   |
|____|   |
| B  | D |
|____|   |
| C  |   |
|____|___|
```

Is it possible? If yes, how?

I tried using colspan and rowspan to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by using layout specifically by using flex.

**Example Code:**

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',

    launch: function () {
        Ext.Viewport.add({
            xtype: 'panel',
            title: 'Flexbox Layout Example',
            items: [{
                xtype: 'panel',
                layout: {
                    type: 'hbox',
                    pack: 'start',
                    align: 'stretch'
                },
                height: '100%',
                border: 1,
                items: [{
                    xtype: 'panel',
                    flex: 1,
                    layout: {
                        type: 'vbox',
                        pack: 'start',
                        align: 'stretch'
                    },
                    items: [{
                        xtype: 'panel',
                        flex: 1,
                        html: 'Panel 1',
                        border: 1,
                    }, {
                        xtype: 'panel',
                        flex: 1,
                        html: 'Panel 2',
                        border: 1,
                    }, {
                        xtype: 'panel',
                        flex: 1,
                        html: 'panel 3',
                        border: 1,
                    }]
                }, {
                    html: 'panel D',
                    xtype: 'panel',
                    flex: 1,
                    border: 1,
                }]
            }]
        });
    }
});
```

**Link to working fiddle:** 
https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2nio

Comment: Hmm. Never thought about flex. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

[**FIDDLE**](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2nin)

```
items: [{
    html: 'Cell A content'
}, {
    html: 'Cell B content',
    rowspan: 3
}, {
    html: 'Cell C content'
}, {
    html: 'Cell D content'
}]
```

Comment: Thanks for trying to help but I need D to be on the right and I cannot change the order of the cells.